# How to avoid getting thrown out of my component when refreshing a page in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am working on a project with ReactJS and Firebase. I have a component containing a form. When the form is filled, I use a ternary to replace the form by another component - either A,B or C. When on any of these components, refreshing the page will direct me back to the form and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated

**FormComponent.js**

```
function AccesClientsForm() {
    
        const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
        const [clients, setClients] = useState([])
        const [client, setClient] = useState('')
        const [rapportType, setRapportType] = useState('')
        const [showRapportPassage, setShowRapportPassage] = useState(false)
        const [showCheckMateriel, setShowCheckMateriel] = useState(false)
        const [showSuiviQualite, setShowSuiviQualite] = useState(false)
    
        const [error, setError] = useState(false);
        
        //logic to find client in a firestore "clients" collection based on provided email
    
        useEffect(() => {
            getClients()
    
        }, [])
    
        const getClients = async () => {
            const data = await ClientDataService.getActiveClients()
            setClients(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))
    
        }
    
        const handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            setError(false)
    
            const clientsArray = []
            clients.map((client) => {
                clientsArray.push(client.client, client.email)
    
            })
    
    
            let indexClients = clientsArray.indexOf(email)
            if (indexClients !== -1) {
                
                setClient(clientsArray[indexClients - 1])
                if (rapportType === 'Rapports de passage') {
                    setShowRapportPassage(true)
                }
                else if (rapportType === 'Checks Matériel') {
                    setShowCheckMateriel(true)
                }
                else if (rapportType === 'Suivi Qualité') {
                    setShowSuiviQualite(true)
                }
                else {
                    alert("Veuillez choisir un type de document")
                }
    
    
            }
            else {
                setError(true)
            }
    
        }
    
        return (
    
            <>
                
                {showRapportPassage === false & showCheckMateriel === false & showSuiviQualite === false ? ( 
               
                    <div>
                    
                            <form >
                                <label className='title'>Confirmez votre Email</label>
                                <input type="email" placeholder="Votre Email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} required />
    
    
                                <div className="formInput">
    
                                    <select value={rapportType} onChange={(event) => { setRapportType(event.target.value) }} required>
                                        <option>Type de document ?</option>
                                        <option>Rapports de passage</option>
                                        <option >Checks Matériel</option>
                                        <option>Suivi Qualité</option>
    
                                    </select>
                                </div>
    
                                <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Afficher vos rapports</button>
                                {error === true ? <span>nom d'utilisateur ou email incorrect</span> : ""}
    
                            </form>
                        </div>
    
                    
                ) : showRapportPassage === true ? (
                    <ComponentA client={client}/>
                ) : showCheckMateriel === true ? (<ComponentB client={client}/>) : (<ComponentC client={client}/>) }
    
            </>
        )
    }
```

Comment: The state will be reset on page refresh, you need to persist data maybe using webstorage ...